# how to directly work with `xsl` from Java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd, jaxb

Using `Java` to write `xml` strikes me as [perhaps](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/130267/102335) not the best match.  Is this just because it's new and unfamiliar, perhaps?

Rather than generating `JAXB` source code from `xml` might it not be more flexible to work with `xml` files directly?  What I mean is, cannot the middle-man be cut out?

If `JAXB` can generate source code for the class files to manipulate `xml` might there a tool which uses `JAXB` without creating concrete boiler-plate?

If there's simply a mis-match making this impossible please elaborate.  Or, if it's simply out of reach, what are the obstacles?

Comment: First: neither Java nor XML is new. Working directly with xml is a bit complicated because of the structure of xml. If you want it simple use csv-files or property-files.

Comment: is there a language which fits xml like a glove?  I'm surprised there's not an xml language specific to processing xml.  Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the role of xslt.  I mean, even using xslt it must still be invoked...

Comment: One possibility in Java is XMLDecoder and XMLEncoder. It's relative easy to read or write objects from/to XML.

Comment: AS for "I'm surprised there's not an xml language specific to processing xml", XSLT seems to fit that bill of being an XML language to process and generate XML. XQuery certainly is also designed to process XML and lots of its syntax like direct element constructors allow you use XML syntax.

Comment: Have you considered using Velocity rather than xslt?

Comment: For now I'll stick with JAXB, but, yes, xslt and velocity are on my radar.  JAXB strikes me as quite useful but boilerplate to an extreme which makes me question whether it cannot simply be removed.  But I readily acknowledge that I don't know what I don't know, never mind what I know I don't know.